# React Native: fetch function sends null body

Tags: javascript, react-native

I use this code to fetch a token successfully if I run it from node. However, it fails, and I notice the body received in the server end is empty when I run it in React Native. What is wrong in React Native?

```
 function fetchToken() {
    console.log("fetchToken");
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('client_id', '1234567');
    params.append('client_secret', 'abcdefg');

    const url = "https://example.com/token";

    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    fetch(url, {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: params})
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then((resp) => {
           console.log(resp);
       })
       .catch(error => console.error('Unable to fetch token.', error));

     console.log("fetchToken done");
 }
```

Comment: if this is your react native code, switch out node-fetch with react-native fetch  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch

Comment: Fetch in the example of the link is for CSS. The document does not mention how to use it for function call. Could you send me sample code for function call ?